# jQuery Add http:// as prefix to text input if there is none

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, textinput

I have a text input that need an url as value (complete of http://) and I want that if the user don't writes it himself if gets added automatically. My code as follows,

jQuery

```
$('.txtUrl').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var ini = $(this).val().substring(0,3);
        if (ini === 'http'){
            $.noop()
        }
        else {
            // get value from field
            var cur_val = $(this).val(); 
            // do with cur_val
            $(this).val('http://' + cur_val);
        }        
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="txtUrl" />
```

[Problem in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhsCc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing `http` to the three first characters (`substring(0,3)`) of the text which, of course, never will be true. Change it to:

```
var ini = $(this).val().substring(0, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/jMH9b/

`if ($(this).val().match(/^http/))`

regex always better :)

Comment: Regex is always more expensive than string replace.