# Detect if http or https is present in input - if not, add it on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I've taken a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817636/jquery-add-http-as-prefix-to-text-input-if-there-is-none) but the fiddle examples don't seem to be working and I cannot get the guys accepted answer to work either.

I want to create a blur function that detects if the inputted value contains http:// or https://. If it doesn't, prefix it to the value. If it does, then do nothing.

Comment: Give us a basic example of what you tried! The html markup and the code.

Comment: What exact problem are you having? The [jsFiddle of the second answer](http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmix/jMH9b/) works fine for me (note, check the code, you have to press enter for it to work)

Comment: the fiddle on the unaccepted answer in the post works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jMH9b/4/
try this jsfiddl